# spotfire uniquecount in an one to multiple table

Tags: spotfire

I have a table where one id has multiple entries. For each id, as long as there is an entry where mark is "1", it is considered marked. i want to know how many ids are marked. in this case there are 2.

thank you

[image: click here to view my table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like what you want...

```
UniqueCount(If([Mark] = 1,[ID]))
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! just a follow up of this question. say i change the marking to "0,1,2" and i want to know how many ID has 1 and how many ID has 2. i am trying to use a bar chart to present it. do you know what should i use in my value axis?

Comment: @BenWang there are a couple of ways around this. You can use a COLOR BY option in your bar chart to separate the `[Mark]` values. Or, you can enter three separate expressions similar to the one above and just replace the `[Mark] = 1` with your respective values. So you'll have 3 expressions on your value axis. Either option should yield the same results.

Comment: @BenWang no problem. Be sure to accept correct answers and upvote helpful ones on SO. Good luck with your analytic.